# How can I create an array from files in a project group in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift2

If I have a group in a project called 'sounds', how can I create an array from files in that group? I think this is probably not quite the same as looking in a physical path on disk.

I tried the following:

```
var docsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! + "/sounds";
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()


var error: NSError?
var docsArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docsPath, error:&error)

println(docsArray) // outputs nil
```

The sounds are not in a physical folder on disk but is there a method to address the group by name?

The group was created by right-clicking the project tree and selecting 'New Group'

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode the yellow folders are virtual folders without an equivalent in the file system. To create a real (blue) folder drag a folder containing the sound files into the project tree and select "Create folder references" in the dialog window.

To append a path component to a path I'd recommend to use the designated method

```
let docsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("sounds")
```

Comment: so it is not possible to address a virtual folder from code?

Comment: Not in Objective-C / Swift. But it's possible with AppleScript. But when your're building your app, you need real folders anyway